# cufon is creating issue with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, cufon

I have implement jquery datepicker, Cufon script is also implemented on page. I have implemented some jquery on click events for "Next month", "Previous month" and on dates for Cufon.replace and Cufon.refresh. Problem what I am facing is that when page loads and if I click on next or prev button they work well until I click on any date. Whenever I click next or prev after clicking date an error displayed always in the place of month name stating that "undefined NaN". I am unable to understand that where is problem. If i remove the cufon it works well in all states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, then. Is to not use cufon. Now you are probably wondering... what about my super sweet sweet fonts?

Well, since cufon is a dirty abomination, you need a backup plan. That plan is the @ font-face proeprty. Here is a link to a fontface generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

This will generate a 'bulletproof' Css prop to allow you to use your fonts. Then,y ou just set the font family attribute in your jQuery UI theme, to alter the text.

Cufon needs to essentially 'scrape' the screen and do its ultra-stanky text-on-white-space-splitty-canvas-wrappy-magic. The statefulness, therefore as well as the ability of the datepicker to 'read itself' could be compromised. I understand you hooked up 'refresh' events.. but you actually dug into the widget and changed its html. If there are methods looking for certain jQuery nodes nodes in certain locations - they aren't there. Cufon rearranges, and nested them.

Go forth. Use @fontface. **Eject cufon from your toolset forever**. You shoudl be doing this anyways. Its a Css solution, so it will render very quickly and not interfere with your scripts. This is the preferred method.

Comment: Is this possible to remove anchor from dates and add span instead of anchor. I have tried this but by removing anchor datepicker is unable to populate calender with different colors for specific dates.

Comment: read what I wrote again. You shouldn't be replacing html elements just to support a font. a span and an anchor are not 1:1 swappable. Yes you can technically replace spans with anchors, 

$('a').replaceWith('<span>');

....but it will probably break something else, and so on. this is a bad idea - don't do it. Stop using cufon if you need to attach scripts to a stateful widget that relies on a certain html structure - cufon will alter the structure.

Comment: Yeah its breaking something else in code. Thanks for your kind help.